# ¿inner join no funciona si una llave foranea es null?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, join

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta donde traigo campos específicos de diferentes tablas, todo funciona correctamente, pero cuando una de las llaves foraneas es `null`, ese registro no aparece, **el objetivo es que si aparezca a pesar de que esa llave sea `null`**.

Mi consulta con laravel :

```
Residente::select('residente.*', 'estados.nombreEstado', 'sector.nombreSector', 'localidad.unidad')
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
          ->from('residente')
          ->join('estados', 'estados.id', '=', 'residente.estadoResidente')
          ->join('localidad', 'localidad.id', '=', 'residente.localidad')
          ->join('sector', 'sector.id', '=', 'localidad.sector')
          ->where([
            ["$request->filtro", 'LIKE', "$request->buscar%"]
          ])
          ->paginate(6);
```

para este caso el **campo** que puede o no aparecer **null** en la tabla **residente** es **"localidad"** **(residente.localidad==null)**. según estuve investigando se puede hacer con subconsulta  dando uso al método `whereExists()` pero sin utilizar los join, sin embargo no logré entender bien el concepto. aquí el enlace de donde halle el concepto mencionado : [Ignore the joins without any result in SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191568/ignore-the-joins-without-any-result-in-sql-server).

**Resultados que arroja la consultas:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Resultados esperados :**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco a quien pueda brindarme ayuda.

Comment: La definición de INNER JOIN es justo el comportamiento que estás definiendo. Para conseguir "que no desaparezcan" registros con claves foráneas nulas como comentas, debes utilizar LEFT JOIN o RIGHT JOIN según convenga en la consulta.  Revisa: https://programacionymas.com/blog/como-funciona-inner-left-right-full-join

Comment: Los JOIN trabajan tras el ON con las coincidencias que coloques, es así como define el match que hará entre tabla y tabla. Si por ejemplo encontra en una tabla un NULL y la tabla a la que se hace el INNER JOIN (en tu caso) también tiene NULL o NULLS traerá todos los resultados que coincidan. Si usas LEFT JOIN traerá todos los de la tabla izquierda más aquellos que coincidan (misma idea para RIGTH JOIN).

Answer (score 0):

```
Residente::select('residente.*', 'estados.nombreEstado', 'sector.nombreSector', 'localidad.unidad')
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
          ->from('residente')
          ->join('estados', 'estados.id', '=', 'residente.estadoResidente')
          ->leftJoin('localidad', 'localidad.id', '=', 'residente.localidad')
          ->leftJoin('sector', 'sector.id', '=', 'localidad.sector')
          ->where([
            ["$request->filtro", 'LIKE', "$request->buscar%"]
          ])
          ->paginate(6);
```

Gracias a los comentarios logré encontrar la solución para este caso, muchísimas gracias!